# Javascript rfr сортирующий и преобразующий текст в html инструмент

Tags: javascript, html

**Привет, народ есть на входе такие строки:**

```html
Transfer: Вопрос: почему сегодня такая плохая погода<br><br> Ответ: Мы сами не знаем<br>Вопрос: хорошо спасибо<br><br>
```

**Нужно найти в этом файле строки начинающиеся со слова "Вопрос" и при выполнении вывести только их, результатом выше должно быть:**

Вопрос: почему сегодня такая плохая погода

Вопрос: хорошо спасибо

Comment: `.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на основе комментария от Денис Степанов.

```js
function onClick() {
  const TEXT = document.getElementById("text").value;
  const QUESTIONS = TEXT.match(/вопрос:.*?(?=<br>)/gi);
  const QUESTIONS_HTML = QUESTIONS.join("<br>");
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = QUESTIONS_HTML;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" value="Transfer: Вопрос: почему сегодня такая плохая погода<br><br> Ответ: Мы сами не знаем<br>Вопрос: хорошо спасибо<br><br>"></input>
<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<div id="question"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как собрать с Input TEXT?